# Cannot Boot From Anything Other Than MacOS

Tags: macos, startup, unix, dual-boot

I wanted to install Linux on my Mac. I made USB installers (with Rufus from my PC and Etcher) but when I boot from it, it shows an error:

> The version of macOS on the selected disk needs to be reinstalled:  Use Recovery to reinstall macOS or select another startup disk.

I installed rEFInd to boot for me, but I can't boot from that either, showing the same error. SIP was always off during these boots (never tried SIP on but I don't think that might help). I tried manually blessing the rEFInd .efi file, still didn't work.

Apparently, my Mac doesn't recognize anything that's not macOS. What can I do to make it recognize these?

[image: The Error]

Comment: You need to says what Mac.  There are roughly 3 sorts of Mac (regarding booting): old Intel, Intel with T2, and Apple Silicon.  Also, you may want to rethink your method of running Linux - it is easier to run Linux in a virtual machine.

Comment: Which Linux? What is the model/year of your Mac? Was the USB installer made with Rufus or Etcher? If Etcher, then from where? Which version of macOS? You do not need to disable SIP  to install most (in not all) Linux. You can also install rEFInd without disabling SIP or using `bless`, however Rod's instructions recommend disabling SIP and uses `bless`. I am not sure what you mean by *"I can't boot from that either"*. Do this mean you can not boot rEFInd or can not boot Linux by using rEFInd. Most Macs recognize rEFInd and most popular Linux.

Comment: @Gilby I am on a MacBook Pro 2018 which is probably old Intel. I use Linux on a virtual machine but the performance is terrible.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I made USB installers with both. Both USB installers as well as rEFInd raise the error of "The version of macOS on the selected disk...".

Comment: If the performance in the VM is "terrible", then address that.  What is "terrible" about it?  What VM solution?  How much CPU/RAM did you give the VM?  You have no reason to dual-boot Linux.

Comment: The Macs with the T2 chip are listed [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862). Can you confirm your Mac has the T2 chip? If you have the T2 chip, then have you [set the Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198) to "No Security" and "Allow booting for external or removable media"?

Comment: @DavidAnderson most likely has the answer to your problem - your Mac is Intel with T2.  But really it is a lot of hassle to dual boot - so much easier to use a VM.

Comment: This question appears be a duplicate of the question [Is there an Ubuntu documented build to run on 2018 MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379012/is-there-an-ubuntu-documented-build-to-run-on-2018-macbook-pro). Although the OP never identified which Linux being used, answers to the duplicate question cover the requirements needed for all Linux.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thank you! That answers my question. (do you want to answer it officially for the other people with the same question?)
Also the link seems to have nothing to do with my question at all, unless I am not understanding something.

Comment: John: Your question would have to be reopened before any answers can be posted. I believe many questions and answers have already been posted involving the setting the T2 chip to "No Security" before trying to install Linux. The link I give also indirectly explains the need for at least Linux 5.4 in order to get the patch that may be required for installation to the internal drive. If you have any further problems installing Linux, you can edit your question and see if the question is reopened. Or, ask a new question.